# Poor performance when calculating averages

Tags: django, performance, e-commerce, average, bigdata

I need to show averages of offer prices. The problem is that I have to calculate the averages for combinations of a many-to-many field. I also have to page all this.

I already did it. The problem is that it has a poor performance, and I'm looking for a way to solve it.

The model looks like this:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    price = DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = PositiveIntegerField()
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
    qualifiers = ManyToManyField(Qualifier)
```

The relevant code to calculate the averages is this:

```
def get_average(product, qualifiers, users=None):
    offers = Offer.objects.filter(product=product)

    if users is not None:
        offers = offers.filter(user__in=users)

    for qualifier in qualifiers:
        offers = offers.filter(qualifiers=qualifier)

    if not offers.count():
        return None

    offers = offers.aggregate(
        quantity_x_price_sum=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'), output_field=FloatField()),
        quantity_total=Sum('quantity')
    )

    # Weighted average
    return offers['quantity_x_price_sum'] / offers['quantity_total']


def get_averages(product, limit=20, users=None):
    averages = []

    colors = product.qualifiers.filter(type=1)
    sizes = product.qualifiers.filter(type=2)
    other = product.qualifiers.filter(type=3)

    qualifiers = [colors, sizes, other]
    combinations = itertools.product(*qualifiers)

    for combination in combinations:
        average = get_average(product, combination, users)
        if average is not None:
            averages.append(average)

            if len(averages) == limit:
                return averages

    return averages
```

The main problem is in itertools.product(*qualifiers). That can generate hundreds of combinations.
And until len(prices) == limit, it has to iterate over each of them and execute the query.

Any help will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: In a first sight, you're creating a list ` combinations = list(itertools.product(*qualifiers))` to get your combinations then your're passing it into a for loop. An improvement to this is creating a generator ` combinations = itertools.product(*qualifiers)` then you can pass combinations into a for loop. This will reduce the overhead for generating a list then iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do a average aggregation with queries themselves?

From Django documentation:

```
# Average price across all books.
>>> from django.db.models import Avg
>>> Book.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('price'))
{'price__avg': 34.35}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/

EDIT: There are more complex ways to query this, hopefully this helps. Unsure how it handles non-numeric data.

Comment: To add to this answer, you should - as a first step - try to do as much with the ORM as possible. Pull everything into Python only if you can't do it in the ORM. This doesn't always apply, but it does to most bigger / intermediate issues.

Comment: I need the weighted average, which is different from just the average (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean). That's why I put that aggregate, to do the calculations.

And I can't calculate on all the offers directly, I have to do for each combination of qualifiers for each product (and then paginate). I think this is the main problem.

Thanks.